# 308 Status code when making http request with httplib cpp

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an `HTTP` request with `httplib cpp` to the following endpoint: http://api.publicapis.org/entries. I'm using the following code:

```
httplib::Client cli("http://api.publicapis.org");

if (auto res = cli.Get("/entries")) {
    if (res->status == 200) {
        std::cout << res->body << std::endl;
    }
} else {
    auto err = res.error();
    std::cout << "HTTP error: " << httplib::to_string(err) << std::endl;
}
```

The body won't log, as I am receiving status code 308. Where is the issue?

Comment: A HTTP 308 is a [Permanent redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308). Your code should respond to that by *following* the redirect and use the new location.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Why when using Postman the request goes through fine though? Where can I find the new location?

Comment: Because "postman" (whatever that is) knows how to read the 308 response and get the new location (from the `Location` header) and just handles everything behind your back. Your code needs to do the same.

Comment: The lib seems to have an option to follow redirects, try setting `cli.set_follow_location(true);`

Comment: This is a typical response to a redirect to https. Look at the address: you're querying a http page... in most cases you can expect a redirect if you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Http 308 is code for permanent redirect, the page has moved...

Check the `Location` header in the response and try with this url.

The lib seems to have an option to follow redirects, try setting `client.set_follow_location(true);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308

Comment: Using the client.set_follow_location(true) I know get HTTP error: Unknown

Comment: didn't try it myself, just looked at the docs... then read Location header from response and manually retry the request using this url

Comment: perhaps the builtin option only considers codes 301 and 302

Comment: It is redirecting to the https endpoint. Thanks for the help.